# Why won't paypal sandbox save my "Log in with Paypal" settings?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Does anyone know why the Paypal developer sandbox does not save when I select an additional OAuth scope?

[PayPal sandbox not saving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMM5A.png)

Comment: solved - there is a hidden error message in the Return URL which is only found when you unhide it. Even though the Return URL makes no sense from my mobile apps perspective and is in a different section to the "Log In with PayPal" section I am forced to put something in it. The form then saves..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the top of the sandbox form, unhide the Return URL, type something in the Return URL. The form will now save.